# Universal coefficients theorem for $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homological-algebra

I would like to know whether the universal coefficients theorem (for homology) holds when the coefficient ring is $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$. This ring is not a PID (so the classical theorem cannot be applied) but at least it is a gcd domain.

More concretely, I am interested in knowing whether the following isomorphism holds, $$H_1(X; \mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]) \otimes_{\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]} \mathbb{Q}(t) \cong H_1(X; \mathbb{Q}(t)), $$ where $\mathbb{Q}(t)$ is the field of fractions of $\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}]$. If the UCT held, then we would be done, since the field of fractions of a ring is always flat and $\mathrm{Tor}$ vanishes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are interested in the Universal coefficient spectral sequence. It involved higher Tor's for homology and higher Ext's for cohomology. For $H_1$ your isomorphism holds for any ring and any module because $H_0$ is always free and $H_{-n}$ are always trivial. For a flat module, the isomorphism will always hold in the homological case regardless of what homological degree you are in because all nonzero Tor's are trivial.

Comment: Do you know a reference where this UCSS is constructed and hopefully I can also read about the two claims you make?

Comment: @Minkowski Looking around it seems like not many direct references, but here is the construction. We need 2 facts which you can easily read about. 1) For a levelwise free chain complex C, the tensor product $C \otimes M$ for a module $M$ is quasi-isomorphic (i.e. same homology) as $C \otimes F(M)$, where $F(M)$ is the free resolution of $M$. 2) Given a [double complex](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/spectral+sequence+of+a+double+complex), there is a spectral sequence starting at the horizontal homology of the vertical homology and ending at the total homology of the double complex.

Comment: Now it is easily seen that the total homology of the double complex given by tensoring $C_i$ and $D_j$ together for all $i,j$ is the homology of $X \otimes D$. So for $C$ levelwise free and $D=F(M)$ we get a spectral sequence converging to the homology of $C \otimes F(M)$ which is the same as the homology of $C \otimes (M)$.

Comment: The $E_2$ page is now easily seen to comprise the information $\operatorname{Tor}^R_{i}(H_j(C),M)$ by construction.